# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: name is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

In my bot I get the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: name is not defined

The problem happens when I am not in a voice channel and type the command `!ph`.

The command tag the helpers role (`@helpers`) and the staff role (`@staff`) and this work when I am in a voice channel.

The error is in `if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);` in the main config.

The code for the `!ph` command.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    let room = message.member.voiceChannel.name;

    if (!room) {
        return message.channel.send("<@&587662170548994076>" + " <@&594077199859187723> " + "**!צריך את עזרתכם** " + target + " ** :name_badge: המשתמש לא נמצא בשום חדר**\n");
    } else {

        return message.channel.send("<@&587662170548994076> <@&594077199859187723> " + target + " **!צריך את עזרתכם** \n" + " `` " + room + " `` " + "**המשתמש נמצא בחדר :bell:**");

    }

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ph"
}
```

The code for the bot:

```js
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
let xp = require("./xp.json");
let purple = botconfig.purple;

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
        console.log("Couldn't find commands.");
        return;
    }

    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${f} loaded!`)
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    });

})


bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);
    bot.user.setGame("PeDiXOL Server!");
});

bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)

    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
    if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);

    let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 8
    console.log(xpAdd)

    if (!xp[message.author.id]) {
        xp[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level: 1
        };
    }

    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtLvl = xp[message.author.id].level * 300;
    xp[message.author.id].xp = curxp + xpAdd;
    if (nxtLvl <= xp[message.author.id].xp) {
        xp[message.author.id].level = curlvl + 1;
        let lvlup = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Level Up!")
            .setColor(purple)
            .addField("New Level", curlvl + 1);

        message.channel.send(lvlup).then(msg => {
            msg.delete(5000)
        });

    }

    fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });

});

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

This need to output, when you are not in a voice channel, something that tag the helpers and staff and say you are not in a voice channel.

When you are in a voice channel this output `the username needs help` and tag the staff and helpers and say the voice channel name the user connected to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.member.voiceChannel` is undefined, so `message.member.voiceChannel.name` will throw an error. You can fix it like this:

```js
let room = message.member.voiceChannel;

if(room == undefined) {
  return message.channel.send("<@&587662170548994076>" + " <@&594077199859187723> " + "**!צריך את עזרתכם** " + target + " ** :name_badge: המשתמש לא נמצא בשום חדר**\n");
} else {
  return message.channel.send("<@&587662170548994076> <@&594077199859187723> " + target + " **!צריך את עזרתכם** \n" + " `` " + room.name + " `` " + "**המשתמש נמצא בחדר :bell:**");
}
```

Comment: If `message.member.voiceChannel` is undefined, `room` will be undefined. `room.name` will be reading the property `name` of undefined, returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`message.member.voiceChannel` is undefined because the user isn't in a voice channel. When you try to read its `name` property, the error is thrown because the voice channel is undefined.

Prior to using `message.member.voiceChannel`, make sure it's defined. The `if` statement below will return true when `message.member.voiceChannel` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), meaning the user is *not* in a voice channel.

```js
if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return; // Or return an error message.

let room = message.member.voiceChannel.name;
```

Also make sure to catch any rejected [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in your code to prevent an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Do so with [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statements or [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods.